# JQuery dialog help showing 2 dialogs

Tags: jquery

I have 2 separate ordered lists that I'd like to display in a single dialog but for some reason, I get two dialogs coming up. Why is this?

```
<ol>
 Test
 <li>a</li>
 <li>b</li>
</ol>

<ol>Test
 <li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
</ol>
```

---

```
      $.ajax({
        url: 'test.asp',
        data: vals,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data){
          var $dialog = $(data.message)
          .appendTo('body')
          .dialog({
             modal: true
          });
        }
      });
```

The above produces 2 dialogs.

Comment: Are you sure  data.message is not an array with 2 `<ol>` lists? Also, did you not log that in console?

Comment: @inhan, data.message is a json array with two `ol` tags with its data inside.

Comment: All I want to do is to show the user 2 separate ordered lists within a single dialog. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap them in a single `<div>` like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.asp',
    data: vals,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data){
        var $dialog = $("<div>").append(data.message)
        .appendTo('body')
        .dialog({
            modal: true
        });
    }
});
```

The problem was caused by having two valid HTML strings in your response as an array. When you call $(data.message) jQUery creates two separate `<ol>` elements and returns them in an array. Then when you call `.dialog()` on that *array* each element becomes the top node inside a dialog.

Comment: Thank you. This was making me nuts. Thanks for the explanation as well. :)